# Text File Handling with SQL Database - Visual Basic

Tags: sql, vb.net, text-files, file-handling

I have a text file contains delimited records.

```
1243;jhhf';982u4k;9u2349;huf8
kij;9238u;98ur23;jfwf;03i24
```

I need to replace the value of 4th part of every record with the value returned from SQL database (`Select X from T where C='4Th part from the flatfile'`).

Regards,
SAnthosh.

Comment: Note that part of my answer is taken from my previous answer on OP post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922426/text-file-handling-in-visual-basic/8922498#8922498

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim newLines As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand()
SQLCmd.Connection = sqlConn
Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(filename)
sqlConn.Open()
For Each line As String In lines
    Dim parts As String() = line.Split(";")
    SQLCmd.CommandText = "Select X from T where C=""" & parts(3) & """"
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read()
        parts(3) = dr("X")
    End While
    newLines.Add(String.Join(";", parts))
Next
File.WriteAllLines(filename, newLines.ToArray())
sqlConn.Close()
```

Comment: System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message="Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: @user1157902: this means that `line.Split` returned less than 4 parts, so your file is not the way you described I think....

Comment: A;B;C;160;D /n X;Y;Z;161;W /n P;Q;R;162;S/n A;B;C;163;D/n (4 lines ) This is the content. i'm just testing before implementing into the actual.

Comment: @Santhosh_ms3: I tried my code and it works for me; I edited it because datareader name was wrong, but I can't reproduce your error. Are you sure about "/n"? Is that a newline?

Comment: yes its(\n) a newline. Actually i got an error {"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."} so closd the Sqldr as SQLdr.close() . after that geting the exception "Index was outside the bounds of the array

Comment: @Santhosh_ms3: hey, you have to debug your app!! Put a breakpoint on `SQLCmd.CommandText = ...` line and check (for every line in your file) that parts.Length is really five as it should. You can do lot of things to find the problem... it is called debugging! :)

Comment: THanks marco. THat was the issue. THere were spaces in 5th and 6th line. so added a condition if If parts.Length > 1. Can you suggest any books for rookies ?

Comment: @Santhosh_ms3: sorry, I've started coding almost 30 years ago, so I'm not familiar with books for newbies sold today. I saw you stripped "accepted" away from my answer: is there a particular reason?

Comment: @Santhosh_ms3: no, you did not accept neither this, nor the other. Are you sure you did? See [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)